# Blinking element Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is an html div element:

```
<div id="elem">A blinking element</div>
```

This is the Javascript code:

```
let elem = document.getElementById("elem");
setInterval(() => elem.hidden = !elem.hidden, 1000);
```

The code is to make the element blink after a second, why is the function in `setInterval` `elem.hidden = !elem.hidden` what does it mean, I mean the function

Comment: What specifically do you want to know? Which part of the syntax do you not understand?

Comment: elem.hidden = !elem.hidden , that's the part i want to know  @FelixKling

Comment: And what part of that do you not understand? Do you know what assignment does (`x = y`)? Do you know what the `!` operator does? Do you know what property access (`x.y`) does?

Comment: Yeah I do, I just don't understand the function, can you break it down?

Comment: I already broke it down. If you know what each of these are doing, then I don't understand what you are still having troubles with.  `elem.hidden` gets the value of property `hidden` of object `elem`. `!` negates that value. `elem.hidden = ...` assigns that value back to property `hidden` of object `elem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` negates. So:

`elem.hidden = !elem.hidden` is setting `elem.hidden` to the opposite value. so if `elem.hidden === true` `elem.hidden` will be set to false and vice versa.

The `setInterval` function essentially just repeats the function every second which is what causes the blinking.

Comment: So what happens every second, does the element change from hidden to visible and when it's visible it changes back?

Comment: Yes. So the hidden attribute gets changed to true which hides it then after a second it changes it to false which shows it.

Answer (score 0):

‘!’ Means ‘not’. So if element.hidden is true !element.hidden is false and vice versa.